# How can I find matches / servers on steam?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

I can only find a single game in Multiplayer → Online mode, how can I find more?

Some images:

- [Server list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXdt6.jpg)
- [Filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kJrx.jpg)
- [My firewall disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuxiv.png)

Comment: Can you add some more details? What steps are you taking? Maybe post a screenshot of the server list so we can see what's going on.

Comment: hehe, Sorry I play private games with people I know only, so you can not see my server(s) :)

Comment: is this on ranked or open?

Answer (score 1):

If you click view then servers and filter it to dungeon defenders servers, that might work. i had the same problem and it seemed to work for me

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few options I found through internet searching. Try deleting steam/ClientRegistry.blob and a steam restart.